# Import large calendar into Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, import, icalendar

I tried to import a calendar file (.ics file) into Google Calendar, but it gave me an error message:

> Processed 0 of 0 events
>
> The file you tried to import is too large

How do I import it?

I tried reading the [Google Calendar Help page discussing problems importing](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/45654), and read the entry relating to the above error message, but it contained no useful information.  https://www.dirtydandydesign.com/post/155808218272/export-heavy-calendars-ics-more-than-1-mb-to mentions splitting the .ics file into multiple parts but does not contain detailed instructions on exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is a file size limit, of about 1MB or 1.5MB on import files.  The solution is to manually split up the .ics file into multiple parts.

Basically, the format of an .ics file is

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
calendar settings
BEGIN:VEVENT
event stuff
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
event stuff
END:VEVENT
...
END:VCALENDAR
```

To split it up into multiple parts, you need to keep the `BEGIN:VCALENDAR` and `calendar settings` and `END:VCALENDAR`, and split up the VEVENTs into multiple files.  So, you can create a file 1.ics that has

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
calendar settings
<first half of VEVENTs>
END:VCALENDAR
```

and another file 2.ics that has

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
calendar settings
<second half of VEVENTs>
END:VCALENDAR
```

Now import 1.ics, then import 2.ics, and you'll be good.  You might need to split up into more than 2 files; split it up into files that are each smaller than 1MB.

See https://www.dirtydandydesign.com/post/155808218272/export-heavy-calendars-ics-more-than-1-mb-to for details.

Comment: According to [Fix problems importing](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/45654) the size limit for ICS files is 1 MB. (note: different file storage systems might report different file sizes, i.e.  a server might show one value a client might show another value)

Comment: @Rubén, ahh, so it does, but confusingly, it doesn't show that information on the main page or under "Processed x of y events" (the specific error message I got), but only shows it if you click on the page's listing of an error message that I didn't get ("Google calendar is temporarily available" - not an error that I got).

Comment: I agree that this info should be easier to find. It will be nice that the error message include a complete description.